# program stuck at getResponseCode()

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am writing an android application where i need to parse json from a url .
The program freezes after getResponseCode() , displaying no error.
The debugger displays " application is running". but the program is stuck. My code is :

```
HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(status);

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                String json = sb.toString();
                try {

        jArray = new JSONArray(json);
        jObj = new JSONObject[jArray.length()];
       //Get each object from JSON Array
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
            jObj[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Something wrong",""+e.toString());
                }

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

it works for all other urls except one.
Any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: r u calling this in background

Comment: I have it in AsyncTask

Comment: so your app not responds when you make web call

Comment: it does for all urls except one (api s to be precise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case it was a server issue .